# Creating Lambda Snapstart with Typescript CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

Does anyone know how to activate with typescript CDK? There is literally no documentation from AWS how to set it up with their Lambda SDK.

any sample code?

Comment: What is the runtime for for your lambda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the TypeScript sample:

```
import * as lambda from "@aws-cdk/aws-lambda";
import * as cdk from "@aws-cdk/core";

export class LambdaSnapStartStack extends cdk.Stack {
    constructor(scope: cdk.App, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
        super(scope, id, props);

        const lambdaFunction = new lambda.Function(this, "lambda-function", {
            functionName: "MyPrettyFunction",
            runtime: lambda.Runtime.JAVA_11,
            memorySize: 1024,
            timeout: cdk.Duration.seconds(30),
            handler: "my_lambda.lambda_handler",
            code: lambda.Code.fromAsset("my_lambda.zip")
            // other properties
        });

        // Enable SnapStart
        const cfnFunction = lambdaFunction.node.defaultChild as lambda.CfnFunction;
        cfnFunction.addPropertyOverride("SnapStart", { ApplyOn: "PublishedVersions" });
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't this missing publishing a version for it to work? I think that if you activate the SnapStart on PublishedVersions without publishing one it does basically nothing, but not totally sure. Source: https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/23153#issuecomment-1331196914

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so it's possible for any runtime other than `java11` and `java17`.

[AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/snapstart.html#snapstart-runtimes)

> SnapStart supports the Java 11 and Java 17 (java11 and java17) managed runtimes. Other managed runtimes (such as nodejs18.x and python3.10), custom runtimes, and container images are not supported.

If your lambda uses Java runtime then you need to use Snapstart property, otherwise at this moment you cannot use Snapstart feature for your lambda.

Ref: [Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/snapstart-activate.html#snapstart-cfn-sam)

> AWS Cloud Development Kit (AWS CDK): Use the SnapStartProperty type.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/java/software/amazon/awscdk/services/lambda/CfnFunction.SnapStartProperty.html

Comment: I agree regarding the runtime. I've updated the snippet.